# Localization of Windows Installer default strings in WiX

Tags: internationalization, wix

I am trying to localize a Wix installation. It is very simple, no custom dialogs or strings. Only using `WixUI_InstallDir`-dialogs.

I thought setting `Product/@Language=1044` and `Package/@Language=1044` would have the installer talk Norwegian.
Partly.
The dialogs are in English, but status update while the progress-bar moves are in Norwegian.

I have tried following the guide http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson8.php#8.9

However, all the "default" strings built into Windows installer, do I need to translate those?
Or is there some localization-file available somewhere on the web I should download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog strings must be localized. WiX comes with 40 sets of loc strings; you specify them using the -cultures switch to Light.exe or the Cultures property in a .wixproj.

Comment: Is there a list of which the 40 is somewhere?

Comment: @leiflundgren The list can be found at [WiX Localization Project](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/loc/index.php)

Comment: @leiflundgren Looking at [WiX Localization Project](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/loc/index.php), I can see that Norwegian translation has not been done for WiX 3. It means you'll have to use WiX 2 for your setup project, or to translate the required strings yourself.

Comment: The following locales are in WiX v3.5 RTM, though not all are complete:

ar-SA
bg-BG
ca-ES
cs-cz
da-dk
de-de
el-GR
en-us
es-es
et-EE
fi-FI
fr-fr
he-IL
hi-IN
hr-HR
hu-hu
it-it
ja-jp
kk-KZ
ko-KR
lt-LT
lv-LV
nb-NO
nl-nl
pl-pl
pt-BR
pt-PT
ro-RO
ru-ru
sk-SK
sl-SI
sr-Latn-CS
sv-SE
th-TH
tr-TR
uk-ua
zh-CN
zh-HK
zh-tw